# How to pass output from a powershell function into a Bash Script in a YAML pipeline

Tags: bash, powershell, azure-devops

In my YAML pipeline I have following sequence

- Check the packages that are changed through a powershell function
  where I pass a path to the folder as parameter and run git diff to
  find exit code 0 or 1
- I then want to receive the output 0 or 1 in a Bash@3 in my yaml
  pipeline and run an "if condition" to either skip or build a package

Here is my powershell function

```
function packageChangeChecker {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $pathToPackage    
        )
    git diff HEAD~:src/$pathToPackage HEAD:src/$pathToPackage  --exit-code --quiet    
     if($LastExitCode -eq 1) {
variable=filesChanged;isOutput=False]$false"
        return $false
     }      
    elseif($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        return $true
    }
    }
```

Here is my Bash@3

```
- task: Bash@3
        displayName: 'detectChanges'
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
              pathToPackage="docker-dotnet-app-aks2/"
              export filesChanged = "powershell.exe "& { . .\package-change-checker.ps1; packageChangeChecker $pathToPackage}""
```

i then want to use output of files changed in an If condition in my YAML pipeline before calling a template to build the package

```
- ${{ if eq(stageDependencies.Deploy.preBuildChecks.outputs['detectChanges.filesChanged'], true) }}
```

I have tried passing on the output of powershell functions as below

```
filesChanged = "powershell.exe "& { . .\package-change-checker.ps1; packageChangeChecker $pathToPackage}""
```

I get error in my pipeline with above approach

What's the best way to pass output of powershell function back to the Bash to be used under If condition in YAML file further down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a supplement based on the other answers under this topic, please be advised that you should **not** use conditional insertion (`${{if}}`) to evaluate an output variable `filesChanged` that is generated at runtime, because conditional insertion as template expression is processed at compile time **before** runtime starts (see [Understand variable syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#understand-variable-syntax)).

Instead, you should use `condition` property for a `stage`, `job`, `deployment` job, or `step` to control whether to skip the downstream `stage`/`job`/`deployment`/`step`. Kindly note the [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependency-syntax-overview) depends on how the output variable is generated and how you would use it (across jobs/stages). Check [Levels of output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/set-variables-scripts?view=azure-devops&tabs=bash#levels-of-output-variables) and [dependency syntax overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependency-syntax-overview) for more samples.

Assuming your pipeline outputs the variable in an upstream `job`(**not** a `deployment` job, as it uses a different syntax in downstream evaluation) and the value of `filesChanged` is passed to downstream stage to control whether the downstream stage is to run. Here is a sample for your reference.

```
stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: preBuildChecks
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          $pathToPackage="docker-dotnet-app-aks2/"
          git diff HEAD~:src/$pathToPackage HEAD:src/$pathToPackage  --exit-code --quiet
          if($LastExitCode -eq 1) {
            Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesChanged;isOutput=true]$true"
          }
          else {
            Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesChanged;isOutput=true]$false"
          }
      name: detectChanges
      continueOnError: true
    - task: PowerShell@2
      inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: |
          Write-Host $(detectChanges.filesChanged)

- stage: DownstreamStage
  dependsOn: Deploy
  condition: eq(dependencies.Deploy.outputs['preBuildChecks.detectChanges.filesChanged'], 'True')
  jobs:
  - job:
    variables:
      fileChangedDown: $[stageDependencies.Deploy.preBuildChecks.outputs['detectChanges.filesChanged']]
    steps:
    - powershell: |
        Write-Host $(fileChangedDown)
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the code. I tried PowerShell@2 instead of PS function and used condition instead of if condition but it just does'nt work for me. "DownstreamStage" only kicks off, If i used condition = ''. Meaning therefore the detectchanges (Powershell@2) just doesnt return the value. I have tried to return $true or 'true' or even 'go' but it just doesnt work.

Comment: it finally worked i.e. the condition works fine and the variable is visible in DownstreamStage when i ran commands in Bash shell instead of Powershell 'detectChanges'.  Many thanks for every one's help

Answer (score 0):

See: [How to get output from Azure Devops Powershell YAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55617807/how-to-get-output-from-azure-devops-powershell-yaml)

And: [How to use output of a powershell command as parameters in Azure pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59425275/how-to-use-output-of-a-powershell-command-as-parameters-in-azure-pipeline)

Azure DevOps has predefined variables for this purpose:

```
function packageChangeChecker {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string] $pathToPackage    
    )
    git diff HEAD~:src/$pathToPackage HEAD:src/$pathToPackage  --exit-code --quiet    
    if($LastExitCode -eq 1) {
        return $false
    }      
    elseif($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
        return $true
    }
}
```

Edit: In your Bash script, you can loop over the services and call the PowerShell.

```
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'detectChanges'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
        services=("service1" "service2" "service3")
        for service in "${services[@]}"
        do
            filesChanged=$(powershell.exe -Command "& { . .\package-change-checker.ps1; packageChangeChecker $service}")
            echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesChanged;isOutput=true]$filesChanged"
            if [ "$filesChanged" = "True" ]
            then
                # code
            else
                # code
            fi
        done
```

Try this and let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin Iszac. We have 7 apps that have at least 10 or more services. Services means folders with c# files that i want to git diff to determine which ones have changed. That's why i thought of having a function in ps1 file format that i can call recursively hence i didnt use powershell@2 function. Which as you suggested was a simpler approach.

Comment: But problem with powershell function is that it returns everything not just true or false in this case. e.g. as we have write-output statement. it will also include in the output of it as well. which makes powershell@2 a better proposition perhaps. What do you suggest keeping in mind the recursive calls i need to make?

Comment: 'filesChanged=$(powershell.exe -Command "& { . .\package-change-checker.ps1; packageChangeChecker $pathToPackage}")' worked as i can now print the output.

Comment: I'm using if condition as below '  - ${{ if eq(variables.filesChanged, 'True') }}:
    - template: build-and-push.yml
      parameters:
        buildName: "BUILD"'

Comment: sorry i have lost formatting option now so it will be hard to read for you

Comment: Thanks @Shamrai Aleksander. I have described the reason for using powershell function above and yes i have used fetch depth 0. git diff didnt work without it.

Comment: If you just need `true` or `false` consider removing `Write-Output` and rely on the return statement of the function.

Comment: In your Bash script, you can loop over the services and call PowerShell. `services=("service1" "service2" "service3")` , `for service in "${services[@]}"` then use a `do` loop over the services. `filesChanged=$(powershell.exe -Command "& { . .\package-change-checker.ps1; packageChangeChecker $service}")` and `echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesChanged;isOutput=true]$filesChanged"` ill let you implement the `if` logic which is straight forward.

Comment: I've updated my comment with the section to handle services as you requested.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Iszac, I will consider the loop option. I have removed write-output from the ps function and it returns true or false only. Then i applied the if condition "- ${{ if eq(variables.filesChanged, 'True') }}:" for some reasons the logic doesnt work as it doesnt kick of the template that requires the if condition to be true. I have tried 'True' or 'true'

Comment: Try using the `tr` command `tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'` to convert the output to lowercase before assignment. Then, in the if condition, compare `filesChanged` with `'true'`

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use such a complex approach? )) You may add PowerShell to yaml:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      $pathToPackage="docker-dotnet-app-aks2/"

      git diff HEAD~:src/$pathToPackage HEAD:src/$pathToPackage  --exit-code --quiet    

       if($LastExitCode -eq 0) {
         Write-Output "##vso[task.setvariable variable=filesChanged;isOutput=true]$true"
       }
```

Additionally, do not forget to set the fetch depth to 0: [Shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines#shallow-fetch). The `git diff` will not work without it.